# SELECT * in between MAX and second MAX id of a column WHERE another column equals a certain input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called `orders` with (a.o.) columns `sid` and `q1_requested_by`.
The `sid` column contains a unique id number, incrementing with every new input.

Every now and then there is an input in column `q1_requested_by` with the value `ORDERS PROCESSED`.

I want to select everything from the table which falls in between the latest `ÒRDERS PROCESSED` input and the latest but one `ORDERS PROCESSED` input.

I've tried the following, which doesn't work. It selects nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE sid < (SELECT max(sid) FROM orders
             WHERE q1_requested_by = 'ORDERS PROCESSED')
  AND sid > (SELECT TOP 2 sid FROM orders
             WHERE q1_requested_by = 'ORDERS PROCESSED'
             ORDER BY sid DESC)
ORDER BY sid DESC
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Which dbms, SQL Server or/and MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, in phpmyadmin I found MySQL server 5.5.32-31.0 and MySQL-client version: 5.5.41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would use MySQL constructs:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o
WHERE o.sid < (SELECT max(sid)
               FROM orders
               WHERE q1_requested_by = 'ORDERS PROCESSED'
              ) AND
      o.sid > (SELECT sid
               FROM orders
               WHERE q1_requested_by = 'ORDERS PROCESSED'
               ORDER BY sid DESC
               LIMIT 1, 1
              )
ORDER BY o.sid DESC
```

Comment: This worked! But mind the typo on line 2 (the extra 'o'). :-)

Comment: @blaaat . . . That is not a typo.  That is a table alias.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can just add limit to the second part of the query. Please try this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE sid < (SELECT max(sid) FROM orders WHERE q1_requested_by = 'ORDERS PROCESSED')
AND sid > (SELECT TOP 2 sid FROM orders 
WHERE q1_requested_by = 'ORDERS PROCESSED' ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY sid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will work :)**

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE sid = (SELECT max(sid) FROM orders WHERE sid <>     
            (SELECT max(sid) FROM orders WHERE q1_requested_by = 'ORDERS PROCESSED'))
```